# Nginx rewrite to serve extensionless files as mkv

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a directory with a video file extensionless:

```
 $>ls -lt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 573066 Dec  9  2019 sample
```

if I request:
http://domain/sample
it downloads Okay (sample no extension), but I need nginx to serve the file with a .mkv extension.

So I can request:
http://domain/sample.mkv
and the server to download sample.mkv even the physical file is extensionless.

I've tried to rewrite the extension as follows but I can't get it to work:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rm-ext;
}

location ~ \.mkv$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location @rm-ext {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.mkv last;
}
```

Any advice to achieve this?